# VB.net XML to DataSet - relationship between different DataTables items

Tags: xml, vb.net, datatable, dataset

I'm new to XML and I'm trying to learn how to convert XML into a DataSet with DataTables. (And then save it again later-without looping through the file).
My XML has 2 kinds of groupings I've labeled As and Bs. The Bs are a sub group of the As and may contain Zero or more B elements. The first Table are the As,
the third is the Bs, and the 2nd I believe contains the information of which Bs belong to which As, but this is the part I don't understand.

XML Data

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <As>
   <A>
    <Id>144</Id>
    <Name>Len</Name>
    <Bs>
     <B>
      <N1>1</N1>
      <N2>c</N2>
    </B>
    </Bs>
   </A>
   <A>
    <Id>30</Id>
    <Name>Cr</Name>
   </A>
   <A>
    <Id>29</Id>
    <Name>Cb</Name>
   </A>
   <A>
    <Id>09</Id>
    <Name>Wh</Name>
    <Bs>
     <B>
      <N1>1</N1>
      <N2>s</N2>
     </B>
    </Bs>
   </A>
   <A>
    <Id>01</Id>
    <Name>Ag</Name>
   </A>
   <A>
    <Id>85</Id>
    <Name>Be</Name>
    <Bs>
     <B>
      <N1>1</N1>
      <N2>rS</N2>
     </B>
     <B>
      <N1>3</N1>
      <N2>st</N2>
     </B>
     <B>
      <N1>12</N1>
      <N2>ro</N2>
     </B>
    </Bs>
   </A>
  </As>
```

now I read in the data into an xmlDocument

```
 dim ds as new dataset
 dim xmlDoc as New XmlDocument
 ds.ReadXml(sFilename)
 datagridview1.datasource = ds.tables(0)  ' or 1 or 2 to display contents
```

Now each of ds.tables(2)  entries belongs to a particular entry in the ds.tables(0). ds.tables(1) has 3 items but nothing to display in the datagridview when selected (so the link must be here but I don't know how it works).

My question is where is the index(?) value that relates the 2 together?
If we are looking at the 3rd row in the As table (ds.table(0)), this would point to the 2nd row in the Bs table (ds.table(2)).

Answer (score 0):

The Datatable read XML method only supports xml with limited number of descendants.  The first layer tag is the Dataset name.  Second layer tag is the DataTable names.  Third level is the column names.  Fourth level is the row data.  Once you exceed four levels the Read Xml creates fragmented datatables where the data cannot be recombined properly.  It is better you manually parse the code like below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication48
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("A ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("A Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("B Tagname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("B Value", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement a in doc.Descendants("A"))
            {
                string id = (string)a.Element("Id");
                string name = (string)a.Element("Name");
                if (!a.Descendants("B").Any())
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { id, name});
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (XElement b in a.Descendants("B"))
                    {
                        foreach (XElement element in b.Elements())
                        {
                            string tagname = element.Name.LocalName;
                            string value = (string)element;

                            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { id, name, tagname, value });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```